# Provide Compatability for Various Function Signatures from Shared Library

Tags: c

I am working with a C extension to Python that dynamically loads a third party library and calls its functions. At one point the third party changed one of their function signatures from `foo(int a, int b)` to `foo(int a)`, and I am struggling with how to provide a compatability layer.

In Python I can inspect the version of the third party library and pass that down to the C functions. There I've tried to branch like:

```c
if (version >= 1) {
  foo(42);
} else {
  foo(42, 42);
}
```

While also providing a declaration like `void foo(int a, ...)`

This compiles but segfaults at runtime, likely because the space being allocated for a variadic argument is not the same as an extra argument would be.

I have also tried using the newer declaration of `foo(int a)` but that still yields `too few arguments to 'foo'` during the compilation stage. The older definition won't work here either.

Are there any strategies I can employ to have this code compile and perform the correct behavior at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the function with one type and, when calling the other type, convert its address to a pointer to the type the function is actually defined with:

```
void foo(int a, int b);

void bar(int version)
{
    if (version >= 1) {
        ((void (*)(int)) &foo)(42);
    } else {
        foo(42, 42);
    }
}
```

I have shown the `&` explicitly to make it clear we are taking a pointer to a function, converting it to a pointer to a different type, and using the converted pointer to call the function. However, you can omit the `&`, as functions, like arrays, are automatically converted to pointers when needed.

That includes when calling functions, and the function call operation actually takes a pointer, not a function designator. `cos(x)` is actually `(&cos)(x)`, due to the automatic conversion. That is why we do not need to use `*` with the pointer above when making the function call.

This pushes the behavior defined by the C standard a little, but it should be fine in typical C implementations. Conversion of function pointers to other types of function pointers is defined, and calling a function with the type it is actually defined with is of course defined. The questionable part is that this function will be declared with one type, in `void foo(int a, int b);`, even though its actually definition is another type. However, since the actual definition is out of view of the C compiler, the compiler’s behavior cannot be affected by that. There could only be a problem in an exotic C implementation that used different representations for pointers to different types of functions, which could cause the representation supplied by the linker for the declared `foo` to differ from what the compiler expects.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I very much appreciate the explanation to go along with it